# Judge The “Entirety of a Person” or “Each Person” Favorably?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, pirke-avot-ethicsof

In Avos 1:6 it says …והוי דן את כל האדם why כל האדם and not כל אדם?  Are we being told to judge the “entire” person favorably or “each” person favorably?

Comment: If it would mean “the entire person” then how would you translate ״והוה שפל רוח בפני כל האדם״?

Comment: @שלום I have בפני כל אדם

Comment: @shmosel, true there are different versions, see Siddur Tehillas Hashem, and Likutei Sichos Chelek 3

Answer (score 2):

See Hon Ashir (הון עשיר) who says:

> והוי דן את כל האדם. הידוע, שהוא בנוני, כמ"ש הר"ב. והיינו דלא קתני אדם
> סתם, בלא הא:

Meaning: It is known that this is an average person כמ"ש הר"ב. That is why it does not say "Adam" without the "Heh".

Answer (score 0):

First many have it as plain kol-Adam without the Hei:
[https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=והוי דן את כל אדם](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%95%D7%94%D7%95%D7%99%20%D7%93%D7%9F%20%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D)

In particular, [Likutei Moharan #282 aka "Azamra"](https://www.sefaria.org/Likutei_Moharan.282.1.1?lang=bi) which is an entire Torah (lesson) on that, has it without the Hei, just Kol Adam, and even in a repetition, "ladun et-hakol lekaf zekhut...' omitting the Adam entirely [like it's not even essential]. And the pshat there is your latter, which should result in the former. That is, by judging any and **each** person favorably, then through that "m'at tov," any littlest good point that you can and should find in him, then he is literally transformed and tantamount to no more a [**entirely**] Resha, wicked, as it says, *"w'od m'at w'ein Rasha"* - "just a little (some good point you should find in him) and this makes him no more a Rasha," and by thus elevating him to the scale of merit he should/will return in Teshuvah [becoming **entirely** different] beh"y NaNach.

> זֶה בְּחִינַת (תהילים ל״ז:י׳): וְעוֹד מְעַט וְאֵין רָשָׁע
> וְהִתְבּוֹנַנְתָּ עַל מְקוֹמוֹ וְאֵינֶנּוּ; הַיְנוּ שֶׁהַפָּסוּק
> מַזְהִיר לָדוּן אֶת הַכֹּל לְכַף זְכוּת, וְאַף־עַל־פִּי שֶׁאַתָּה
> רוֹאֶה שֶׁהוּא רָשָׁע גָּמוּר, אַף־עַל־פִּי־כֵן צָרִיךְ אַתָּה
> לְחַפֵּשׂ וּלְבַקֵּשׁ לִמְצֹא בּוֹ מְעַט טוֹב, שֶׁשָּׁם אֵינוֹ רָשָׁע.
> וְזֶהוּ: וְעוֹד מְעַט וְאֵין רָשָׁע ..
>
> This is the aspect of “In yet a little bit the wicked man is not; you
> will reflect upon his place and he will not be there” (Psalms 37:10).
> That is, Scripture warns to judge everyone favorably. Even if you see
> that he is completely wicked, you must search and seek the little bit
> of good in him, wherein he is not wicked. This is: **In yet a little
> bit the wicked man is not** ...